# Use of %found and %notfound

Tags: oracle, plsql, database-cursor

Why `%found` and `%notfound` cursor attributes both exists? I believe either of them can do the same task?

Comment: Not sure what you mean. They are the opposite of each other? And both are explained [in the documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/12.2/lnpls/static-sql.html#GUID-F1FE15F9-5C96-4C4E-B240-B7363D25A8F1).

Comment: Either of them alone would suffice, I agree. `not %notfound` is equivalent to `%found`. I assume they both exist for programmer convenience; it is not unheard of to see programmers who don't understand double negation.